# JQuery lines don't execute after CSS source change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, fadein

I come to you with an issue that appears only with *Firefox* browser.
I have a page that load pictures series, that can have a white background or a black one, depending on a certain value `$("#selback").val()=="black"`.

So, normally, with the "white" version, when the page loads, it does some size stuff among other things and then displays the image slider container and then a specific image of this slider.
With the "black" version, i first change the CSS `src` and some other elements in the page, and then do exactly the same stuff as above : display the image slider and then a specific image of this slider.

Well, it works everywhere except in *Firefox* where the last part (image slider & image display) doesn't occur, though no error is detected...

I show you below the important parts of the code

```
var css=""; 
if ($("#selback").length){          
    if ($("#selback").val()=="black"){
        css = "black";          
        $('#style-css').attr('href','<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/style_black.css?v=<?= time() ?>');
        /* other image src changes here */
    }
}       
if ($(".slider_inner").length){$(".slider_inner").fadeIn(2000, function(){console.log("Slider displayed");});} // LOG DISPLAYED BUT NOT EFFECTIVE
if ($(".slider").length){
    var cur = $(".slider .slide").last();
    cur.fadeIn(2000,function(){console.log("Picture displayed");}); // LOG DISPLAYED BUT NOT EFFECTIVE 
    /* other stuff here */
}
```

To sum up :
Works in any browser but in Firefox, `.slider_inner` and `cur` are not displayed though the CSS change is ok, and the logs say it's ok too...

Please note that I copied-pasted the entire `style.css` `into style_black.css` and the issue is still here, so does not seem to be a CSS problem.

Here is the concerned part of `style_black.css`

```
.slider {position:relative;width:100%;height:1100px;overflow:hidden;background-color:#ddeeff;box-sizing:border-box;}
.slider_prev {position:absolute;top:45%;left:0em;width:15px;height:28px;background-image:URL('./img/ico_prev_white.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;background-size:100%;z-index:1;opacity:.5;transition:opacity .5s;cursor:pointer}
.slider_next {position:absolute;top:45%;right:2em;width:15px;height:28px;background-image:URL('./img/ico_next_white.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;background-size:100%;z-index:1;opacity:.5;transition:opacity .5s;cursor:pointer}
.slider_prev:hover, .slider_next:hover {opacity:1}
.slider_inner {display:none;position:relative;width:1200px;height:1100px;box-sizing:border-box;background-color:#ffeedd}
.slider .slide {display:none;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background-color:transparent;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;background-size:contain;cursor:pointer}
```

and the same part from `style.css`

```
.slider {position:relative;width:100%;height:1100px;max-height:1100px;overflow:hidden;background-color:#fff;box-sizing:border-box}
.slider_prev {position:absolute;top:45%;left:0em;width:15px;height:28px;background-image:URL('./img/ico_prev.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;background-size:100%;z-index:1;opacity:.5;transition:opacity .5s;cursor:pointer}
.slider_next {position:absolute;top:45%;right:2em;width:15px;height:28px;background-image:URL('./img/ico_next.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;background-size:100%;z-index:1;opacity:.5;transition:opacity .5s;cursor:pointer}
.slider_prev:hover, .slider_next:hover {opacity:1}
.slider_inner {display:none;position:relative;width:1200px;height:1100px;max-height:1100px;box-sizing:border-box}
.slider .slide {display:none;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background-color:#fff;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;background-size:contain;cursor:pointer}
```

Comment: Can you see any CSS problems in the dev tools in FF?

Comment: We need to see the relevant CSS part too. Or could it be just a browser's cache issue?<== edit: i guess no because you seem to use uncached version `v=<?= time() ?>`

Comment: @ovokuro i edited my post to show the css part

Comment: @A.Wolff not a cache problem since as you mentionned it the css is refreshed (and i empty my cache before each test)

Comment: In `style_black.css`, `slider` and `.slider_inner` have no `max-height` and `.slide` has a transparent `background-color`. Only differences I can see, any help?

Comment: Have you got same issue if you load by default the "black" version? I meant not editing dynamically the style source

Comment: @ovokuro yes i tried to add the max-height but no effect. Even when i copy-paste the entire style in style_black, nothing changes...

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried to copy-paste the style_black as the default one and the slider_inner & slide appears as expected. So it really seems to be a problem with the dynamic load of the CSS

Comment: `CSS change is ok` Do you mean the new rules appear when checking them in your dev tool? If so, any of them are overloaded by any older rule? Any chance you provide online link replicating your issue?

Comment: @A.Wolff I meant that the style_black.css is well loaded, and that the console logs are displayed as if everything is ok ... You can see the dev website here : http://www.matthieumarce.com/clients/antoinepicard . When on the home page, wtih all series thumbs, click on the first one "Matières d'eau" to see the normal white version, and click on the third one "Cuirs d'eau" to see the black version. You can test it in Firefox and other browser

Comment: @A.Wolff To be exhaustive, the problem seems to only appear for the first dynamic load of the black CSS : if you open a black serie, then come back on a white one, and then open another black one as "Palais royal", you should see the pictures ...

Comment: It appears that on FF, all `.slide` have `display: none;` rule set, none is visible by default, just like you probably already noted it. Maybe try delaying it: `setTimeout(function(){cur.fadeIn(2000,function(){console.log("Picture displayed");})}, 1000);` See if that change anything?! Or maybe your snipet code isn't called for some reason on FF. EDIT: it could be because `$(".slider").length` returns 0 on FF still for some reasons. That's said, i couldn't help you more currently coz i'm quite busy right now, i'm sorry

Comment: yes the slide_inner & .slide is set on `display:none;` by default and the JQuery part is fading in them (or should...). I tried to delay, but no positive result